# How do I evaluate decimals & floating point numbers in scientific e notation - e.g. {1.23e4}. in postfix?

Tags: c, stack, postfix-mta

I have written my code to evaluate from postfix to result. However, I am stuck at how to do it when the postfix is going to be in decimals & floating point numbers in scientific e notation - e.g. {1.23e4}. Any specific suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 50 /* Size of Stack */

double s[SIZE];
int top=-1; /* Global declarations */
int flag=0;
double pop()
{                      /* Function for POP operation */
  return(s[top--]);
}
double push(double elem)
{ /* Function for PUSH operation */
  if(flag==1){
    int num;
    num=pop();
    s[++top]=elem+10*num;
  }
  else if(flag==0){
    s[++top]=elem;
    flag=1;
  }
}


void main()
{                         /* Main Program */
  char pofx[50],ch;
  int i=0;

  double op1,op2;
  printf("Enter the Postfix Expression:");
  fgets(pofx,100,stdin);
  while( (ch=pofx[i++]) != '\n')
  {
    if(isdigit(ch)) push(ch-'0'); /* Push the operand */
    else if(ch==' ')
      flag=0;
    else
    {        /* Operator,pop two  operands */
      flag=0;
      op2=pop();
      op1=pop();
      switch(ch)
      {
        case '+':push(op1+op2);break;
        case '-':push(op1-op2);break;
        case '*':push(op1*op2);break;
        case '/':push(op1/op2);break;
        case '^':push(pow(op1,op2));break;
        default:
                 printf("Input invalid ... give proper input\n");
                 return 0;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("Result: %lf\n",s[top]);
}
```

Comment: First, rewrite your code so that the whole number is parsed inside the while loop and not char by char with the help of a global `flag`. You could use `strtod` for that, which read floating-point numbers and helpfully tells you the position after the parsing.

Comment: Sorry sir, I did not exactly get your point. Also, I have not used strtod before so I am a bit confused.

Comment: There's always a time to learn new things. Reading floating-point numbers in decimal isn't trivial, so rolling your own might not work. Your current code works, but in my opinion would be improved by parsing number chunks in one go instead of assembling them piecemeal in the `push` function. Anyway, I have posted an answer which might be useful too you.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I evaluate decimals & floating point numbers in scientific e notation ... (?)

To convert  a string into FP value use `strtod()`  [@M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811063/how-do-i-evaluate-decimals-floating-point-numbers-in-scientific-e-notation-e)

---

Yet code has other problems in that the operator symbols `'-'` and `'+'` may also begin valid value tokens like `-123.45`.

```
// insufficient test to determine if the next part of the string is a number or operator.
if(isdigit(ch)) 
  push(ch-'0');
```

Use `strtod()` to convert text to `double` **and** determine if the next part of the string is a `double`.

Alternative code:

```
  const char *st = pofx;
  while (*st) {
    char *end; //location to store end of FP parsing
    double value = strtod(st, &end);
    if (end > st) {
      push(value);
      st = end; 
    } else if (isspace((unsigned char) *st)) {
      st++;
    } else {
      switch (*st) {
        case '+':push(pop() + pop());break; // pop order irrelevant
        case '-':{ double t = pop(); push(pop() - t);break; } // pop order relevant
        case '*':push(pop() * pop());break;
        ...
        default: {
          printf("Input invalid operator: character code %d\n", *st);
          return 0;
        } 
      }  // end switch
      st++;
    }
  }
```

---

Re-write `push()`

```
void push(double elem) {
  if (top + 1 >= SIZE) {
    printf("Stack overflow\n");
    return;
  }
  s[++top] = elem;
}
```

---

Wrong argument to `fgets()`

```
char pofx[50];
// fgets(pofx,100,stdin); // 100??
fgets(pofx, sizeof pofx, stdin); // better
```

Comment: Sir, if u could please have  a look at my code, I am not sure why it is not working after fitting in your adjustments.
{link}: https://onlinegdb.com/BkATeJ8T-

Comment: @AyoanSalim "not working " lacks description.  What what entered? What result did you see? What was expected?

Comment: I entered simple postfix like '45 56 +'. All it gives as output is input invalid operator: character code "random huge number".

Comment: @AyoanSalim Post amended `if (end > st) {` and `printf("Input invalid ... %d\n", *st);`

Answer (score 0):

The function `strtod` from `<stdlib.h>` will parse a `double` for you. It takes the string to parse and a pointer to a string, that will begin with the first unparsed character. (There's a similar function for long integers, `strtol`.)

Here's an example of how this might work in your case. (The code just prints out the tokens and doesn't do any calculations.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int is_number(const char *p)
{
    if (*p == '-' || *p == '+') p++;
    if (*p == '.') p++;

    return isdigit((unsigned char) *p);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *line = " .1 20.1* 1.0e-3+2e+7 * -1.0*";
    const char *p = line;

    while (isspace((unsigned char) *p)) p++;

    while (*p) {
        if (is_number(p, after_op)) {
            char *end;
            double x = strtod(p, &end);

            if (p == end) {
                puts("Illegal number");
                p++;
            } else {
                printf("Number %g\n", x);
                p = end;
            }
        } else {
            int c = *p++;

            switch (c) {
            case '+':   puts("Operator add"); break;
            case '-':   puts("Operator sub"); break;
            case '*':   puts("Operator mult"); break;
            case '/':   puts("Operator div"); break;
            case '^':   puts("Operator pow"); break;
            default:    printf("Illegal char '%c'\n", c);
            }
        }

        while (isspace((unsigned char) *p)) p++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is still very crude, mind you. Strings like `20x21` will be parsed as number 20, unknown character `x` and number 21. While this code is bad at detecting and reporting errors (which really should be done, but it's left as an exercise, yadda, yadda), it works for valid input.

[*Edit*: I've incorporated chux's suggestions and also made the code compatible to read numbers with explicit signs, but that means that the binary operators `-` and `+` cannot immediately be followed by a digit. Pick your poison. I've also allowed the abridged version that leaves out a leading zero, e.g. `.12`, a format that I'm not very fond of.]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir.

Comment: `if (p == end) {` is sufficient rather than `if (x == 0 && p == end) {`.  The following ` while (isdigit((unsigned char) *p)) p++;` serves no purpose as `isdigit((unsigned char) *p)` would never be true here.

Comment: @chux: As someone who doesn't sleep with the C standard under his pillow, I was being overcautious here, I guess.